# PowerDNS slave not authorative

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, mysql, powerdns

I'm running powerDNS 4.3.0 with an master/slave configuration, and when testing the slave replication I come across the following error on the slave:

```
Apr 23 18:06:12 hfr-nl-dns02 pdns_server[17987]: Received NOTIFY for adomain.example from 10.10.30.1:65111
Apr 23 18:06:12 hfr-nl-dns02 pdns_server[17987]: Received NOTIFY for adomain.example from 10.10.30.1:65111 for which we are not authoritative (Refused)
```

And on the master:

```
Apr 23 18:06:12 hfr-nl-dns01 pdns_server[27167]: Queued notification of domain 'adomain.example' to <a public IP>:53
Apr 23 18:06:15 hfr-nl-dns01 pdns_server[27167]: No master domains need notifications
Apr 23 18:06:46 hfr-nl-dns01 pdns_server[27167]: Notification for adomain.example to <a public IP>:53 failed after retries
```

I added the master IP address in the mysql database in the supermasters table (added also private ip's just to test).

```
+--------------+----------------------+---------+
| ip           | nameserver           | account |
+--------------+----------------------+---------+
| 10.10.30.1   | ns2.real-domain.com  | admin   |
| 10.10.30.31  | ns2.real-domain.com  | admin   |
| <a public ip>| ns2.real-domain.com  | admin   |
+--------------+----------------------+---------+
```

---

- 10.10.30.1 is the router
- 10.10.30.31 is the master ip
- 10.10.30.32 is the slave ip

Why does my slave think it's not authoriative?